# Get GPS accuracy in react native

Tags: react-native, geolocation

Is it possible to get the GPS accuracy in react native geolocation? i would like to know how many meters the result might differ in any given time, but I can not find if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can get accuracy by call [getCurrentPosition()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#getcurrentposition) method of class [Geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#geolocation) of **React Native**

This method allows us to request a user’s location at any time. It accepts three parameters — a success callback, an error callback, and a configuration object. The success callback will be passed an object that looks like:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1484669056399.49,
  "coords": {
    "accuracy": 5,
    "altitude": 0,
    "altitudeAccuracy": -1,
    "heading": -1,
    "latitude": 37.785834,
    "longitude": -122.406417,
    "speed": -1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The GPS error of the mesurment can be very different. It can be from 4 to even 40 meters. It all depends of the class of the device you are using, accuracy of the math behind and even from that are you moving or are you standing still. 
You can read the specification of the GPS standard to get more info about that but from my point of view it is impossible to say that X is a fixed error in your result. You should rather focus on the math that allows to minimalize this error, for example you can use low pass filter and/or Kalman filter

Comment: So, do react-native have a method to fetch the accuracy or not?

Comment: Yes it does, just using the geolocation get current position and/or watch position you can get accuracy and a bunch of data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
I am populating a collection of markers to be used with the react-native-maps MapView component.

```js
async _mapLocation() {
        Alert.alert(''+this.state.markers.length);

        await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
                var x: LatLng = {
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                };

                var tempMarkers = this.state.markers;
                tempMarkers.push({latlng: x, title: '', description: ''});
                this.setState({markers: tempMarkers});
            },
            error => {
                Alert.alert(error.message);
            },
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
        )
    }
```